# Observablecollection of custom class not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I am using WPF and have a custom class called eg. "CustomClass" which is used in this way observablecollection.  We have a data grid bound to this OC which works great, the data is displayed and all is well but when any of the items within the observablecollection are updated the underlying grid is not updated accordingly.

Previously we have been creating observablecollections using types directly from the entity data model and this works well (displaying/updating etc) but not when using the custom class.

Is there an interface or something we should be supporting within our custom class to allow the updates to happen?

Thanks.

James.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` tracks changes to the collection, not changes to the objects inside the collection. To track changes in the individual objects you need to make them implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). And if you want to raise a CollectionChanged event when the items inside the collection change, you have to [add that functionality yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7713542/302677)

Comment: Ok, I copied that comment into an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection` tracks changes to the collection, not changes to the objects inside the collection.

To track changes in the individual objects you need to make them implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

And if you want to raise a `CollectionChanged` event when the items inside the collection change, you have to add that functionality yourself, like this:

```
public MyConstructor()
{
    MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    MyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += MyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged;
}

void MyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(MyItem item in e.NewItems)
        {
            MyItem.PropertyChanged += MyItem_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    if (e.OldItems!= null)
    {
        foreach(MyItem item in e.OldItems)
        {
            MyItem.PropertyChanged -= MyItem_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

void MyItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChange e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("MyObservableCollection");
}
```